# Erro no comando sql-insert ao se passar uma variável como parâmetro (python 3)

Tags: mysql, python, sql-insert

Estou tentando passar minha variável "tabela" para o comando mysql, porém está retornando um erro (de sql) durante a execução. O que estou errando?

## Aqui eu criei a variável tabela

tabela = input('Nome da tabela: ')

```
while(tabela not in tabelasCadastradas):
    tabela = input('Tabela não cadastrada. Digite novamente:'.upper())
print(('Menu -> 1- Adicionar questão').upper())
opcaoMenu = input('')
while(opcaoMenu != '1'):
    opcaoMenu = ('Opção inválida. Digite novamente: '.upper())
tema = input('Tema: '.upper())
enunciado = input('Enunciado: '.upper())
```

## Aqui está dando erro

```
crawler.execute('INSERT INTO "%s" (id, tema, enunciado) VALUES (id, "%s", "%s")'%(tabela, tema, enunciado))
```

conn.close()

Comment: Qual é o erro que aparece?

Comment: Diz que eu tenho um erro de sintaxe no comando mysql.

Comment: pymysql.err.ProgrammingError: (1064, 'You have an error in your SQL syntax;

Comment: Quando eu faço crawler.execute('INSERT INTO "nomeTabela" (id, tema, enunciado) VALUES (id, "%s", "%s")'%(tema, enunciado)), funciona perfeitamente. Então eu sei que é realmente algo de errado ao passar a variável tabela como parâmetro.

Answer (score -1):

Resolvido com: `crawler.execute('INSERT INTO`{}`VALUES (id, \'{}\', \'{}\')'.format(tabela, tema, enunciado))`